# Redirect everybody except my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 websites, let's say first.com and second.com
Now on second.com i have some video that i'm using on first.com. via iframe. What i want is, using htaccess how can i deny all visitor to see the website second.com and to redirect them somewhere else, like to google.com for example, and to deny all other websites to link my videos.

I'have this javascript,

```js
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.indexOf('http://second.com') != -1)
{}
else if (ref.indexOf('http://first.com') != -1)
{}
else if (ref.indexOf('http://www.first.com') != -1)
{}
else if (ref.indexOf('http://m.first.com') != -1)
{}
else
top.location.href = 'https://google.com';
```

and works perfectly, but still users can use view-source to see whats on my page on the second.com.

Comment: A user who knows how to view your page's source and extract the required information will not be fooled by your redirects.

Comment: I dont think that htaccess will be fooled by you, just saying.Thnks for the answer, btw

Comment: Ever heard of referrer spoofing? Also, cloaking will be punished by Google, just saying. By the way, you're speaking of `.htaccess`, but posted JavaScript code … I don't understand how that's related.

Comment: Just want to convert it. Want to use htaccess redirection , instead of javascript. 
Ps. im not redirecting anything to Google, it was an example.